# Continue code execution after starting powershell proces

Tags: c#, powershell, selenium-webdriver, xunit

I want to do the following within an XUnit test:

- run a PS script to start a site on IIS
- return to the test class and execute a set of Selenium tests against the site

I can start the site easily enough via PS, but the process is blocking - if I close the PS window, the XUnit test continues, but IIS has obviously stopped so the test fails.

How do I start the IIS process and have the test continue? My PS script is below.

```
$iisExpressExe = '"c:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"'
$path = "..\..\..\.vs\config\applicationhost.config"
$site = "SITE NAME"
$apppool = "Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
$params = "/config:$path /site:$site"
get-process | where { $_.ProcessName -like "IISExpress" } | stop-process
$command = "$iisExpressExe $params"
cmd /c start cmd /k "$command"
```

And the calling C#:

```
    string script = File.ReadAllText("Boot.ps1");
    PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();

    shell.AddScript(script);
    shell.BeginInvoke();

    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    _driver = new ChromeDriver
    {
        Url = "http://localhost:56565/umbraco"
    };

    // do tests here

    _driver.Dispose();
    shell.Stop();
```

This runs, but doesn't dispose the shell...

Comment: Updated with C#

Comment: You are not waiting for the shell to complete properly.

Comment: How should I be doing that? I'm not expecting any returned value, it's simply starting the site...

Comment: `await shell.BeginInvoke();`.  Don't just sleep and call `Stop`.  It might not be finished yet

Answer (score 0):

Create new thread and run ps script from that thread. Then wait several seconds with Thread.Sleep() method in main thread to let iis start site and start selenium tests.

Alternative way to solve problem [`BeginInvoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.begininvoke?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0) `async` method, if you are familiar with async methods.

Comment: Invoke is synchronized method that will wait for result and blocks thread, while powershell process is still active. Alternative way to solve problem BeginInvoke() async method, if you are familiar with async methods.

Comment: @GiorgiChkhikvadze I incorporated your last comment into your answer as it was quite good and possibly answers the OP's question better.  Feel free to revise :)   Oh and +1